# vue.js - Add new value to object after click

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I have something similar to this:

```
arr = [
  { val1: a, val2: b },
  { val1: a, val2: b },
  { val1: a, val2: b } 
]

<div v-for="single in arr">
  <button v-on:click="addSome"></button>
</div>
```

And when i click for example the second button in loop, I want add 'val3': 'c' to clicked object. I tried $add, $set, and tried pass current 'single' and $index... and nothing. What is the correct way to add/edit specified object from loop? Sorry for my English ;) thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<div v-for="single in arr">
  <button v-on:click="addSome($index)"></button>
</div>
```

and then

```
...
"addSome": function (index) {
    Vue.set(this.arr[index], "val3", "c");
}
...
```